# material ui not installing in React Js Project

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui, mern

[image]in my first project material UI is installed successfully, but when I create a new React Js Project and try to install Material-ui it can't be installed

Comment: how are you trying to install? more info please.

Comment: npm install @material-ui/core with this command

Comment: update your question with the error log.

Answer (score 0):

Try this first  `rm -rf node_modules` and reinstall node modules and after that
`npm cache clean` or `yarn cache clean`

Comment: I tried this trick, firstly I reinstalled node from my React Project and then install Material-Ui and it works fine, but do you know what is the exact problem ?

Comment: it's because of the node_modules files got corrupted, just simply reinstall will do the work,  and do use yarn instead of npm, yarn is lightweight.
tip- do remember in future in any such cases occurs just remove node_modules, @SagarDhiman

Answer (score 0):

after reinstalled node module in my React Js project all other libraries installing fine.